# How to set private IP address name to a generic name to show to user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku, ip

I have a rails app that is running on heroku server.

> According to my knowledge, Ip addresses are managed by heroku itself but when I have scanned through Probely vulnerability scanner, it gave me Private IP addresses disclosed. Even I have not displayed my ips to any view.
> Well after some analysis, I came to that point that Remote_addr: 127.0.x.x kind of ip address is showing in the rails error screen and scanner is pointing out for this.

> It also suggested that to fix this issue give a generic name to the ip address so it will be displayed over there instead of its actual value.

But I don't know how to do this on my server or app. **How can I give a name to my private ip address???**

Answer (score 0):

You can't control much on the Heroku apps.
Anyway, `127.x.x.x` is localhost... regardless of what the `X`'s are.

What is suggested is to use the `etc/hosts` to provide a name and don't access the host directly through IP, in case the IP changes. (not available for Heroku afaik)